# Setting scale of profile plot from zero for chip seq profile plot

Tags: deeptools

Figure from this [paper](https://www.embopress.org/doi/pdf/10.15252/embj.201591279) which shows a profile plot in figure4 first figure.
[image: figure].This i guess is made using deeptools perhaps. Meanwhile

When i tried to do similar plot [image: figure 2] the scale doesn't start from 0. So my question how did they set the scale from 0 or the data is as such in other words their data point starts from 0. In my case it starts above 0. So is there a way to scale or normalize to make it start from 0 as i see in the embo paper or its just the characteristics of the data itself generated.

Comment: lol.. your sequencing coverage is super high i guess, such that the average coverage across the genome, even for your control is 10 reads per million? i cannot see a y-axis label

Comment: and did you flip the samples? I think you should not bring it to zero.. it is what it is. If your control is a chip input, this is what I would expect. Note the example you showed above, it is a KO.

Comment: "and did you flip the samples?" that mystery haunts me since I'm the end guy in the chain it our collaborator who are might have jumbled up the samples i have checked  quite  number of times regarding the sample labeling im sure im running the samples as provided.

Comment: "f your control is a chip input, this is what I would expect." Its the  WT ,h2bub chip of control sample

Comment: yes for my plot the color are fine ..my doubt was regarding if the scale can be set to zero which i understand is a bad idea

Comment: yeah you should not.. maybe use a zscale for the axis. Like convert your coverage to a zscale for each gene, take average z scores across all genes and plot that

Comment: you should see a flat line around 0 for your control and a bump for your chip

Comment: "maybe use a zscale for the axis. Like convert your coverage to a zscale for each gene, take average z scores across all genes and plot that " it can be done with deeptools or something else required?

Comment: i code it from scratch.. you can maybe use https://deeptools.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/content/tools/computeMatrix.html and just scale the rows